# Create an array to store date values (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: vb.net

How would you create an array with date values and store it in the format (dd/mm/yyyy). Currently, I also get the time along with the entered date. My aim is to store a person's date of birth in a student database. Is it also possible to restrict DOB to before today?

```
Public Class frmStudentDB
Dim CurrentIndex As Integer
Dim StudentName(20) As String
Dim StudentMark(20) As Integer
Dim StudentDOB(20) As Date = StudentDOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Dim MyFormat As String = "{0, -20}{1,-10}{2,4}"

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim Name As String
    Dim DOB As Date
    Dim Mark As Integer

    If CurrentIndex = 20 Then
        MsgBox("The array is FULL!")
    ElseIf txtName.Text = "" Or txtDOB.Text = "" Or txtMark.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill in the fields as they cannot be left empty")
    ElseIf (IsNumeric(txtMark.Text)) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a number for mark.")
    ElseIf (Integer.Parse(txtMark.Text) > 100) Or (Integer.Parse(txtMark.Text) < 1) Then
        MsgBox("Mark has to be between 1-100")
    Else
        Name = txtName.Text
        CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
        StudentName(CurrentIndex) = Name
        txtName.Clear()

        DOB = txtDOB.Text
        CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
        StudentDOB(CurrentIndex) = DOB
        txtDOB.Clear()

        Mark = txtMark.Text
        CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
        StudentMark(CurrentIndex) = Mark
        txtMark.Clear()

        txtName.Focus() 'Position cursor for input of next student's name
        lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(MyFormat, Name, DOB, Mark))
    End If

End Sub



Private Sub frmStudentDB_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CurrentIndex = -1
    lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(MyFormat, "Name", "DOB", "Mark"))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What issues are you experiencing with this code? Also, VB.NET and VBA are not the same things. They only share a couple of letters, like CARGO and CARPET. In addition this isn't related to Visual Studio itself either, and it couldn't possibly be related to _both_ VS/VB 2010 and 2012.

Comment: With this line of code:Dim StudentDOB(20) As Date = StudentDOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") it says explicit initialisation is not permitted for arrays declared with explicit bounds.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to the site, still learning how to use it properly.

Comment: `StudentDOB.ToString(...)` returns a **single string** which you are right now trying to assign to an array. Since a `String` ≠ `Array` doing so is not possible. If you're trying to impose formatting restrictions that's also not possible. You have to handle that every time you add something to the array, that is, on the `StudentDOB(CurrentIndex) = DOB` line. Since `DOB` is a `Date` you can use your `ToString(...)` overload on that.

Comment: _"My apologies, I'm new to the site, still learning how to use it properly"_ - That is fine. My advice to you is that it's good to read the descriptions of the tags before adding them and to check what others have changed when editing your question. In this case VBA is a completely different language than VB.NET, and the `visual-studio` tag is only meant for questions that are _not_ about code but regarding the Visual Studio application itself.

Comment: I changed the line to  `StudentDOB(CurrentIndex) = DOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` but I stil get time when I add it to the list. E.g. entering today's date it would give me 10/06/2018 00:00:00 in the list.

Comment: I have written an answer below.

Comment: The way to do this is a have an array of `DateTime` objects, which does include a time component, but **ignore** any time component when you display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all**, `StudentDOB.ToString(...)` returns a ***single string*** which you are right now trying to assign to an array. Since a `String` ≠ `Array` doing so is not possible.

If what you're trying to do is to impose formatting restrictions that's also not possible. You have to handle that every time you add something to the array, that is, on the this line:

```
StudentDOB(CurrentIndex) = DOB
```

Since `DOB` is a `Date` you can use your `ToString(...)` overload on that.

**Secondly**, you get the time as well in the list box because you only pass it `DOB`, which allows it to select the format by itself. Instead you should pass it the already formatted string:

```
lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(MyFormat, Name, CurrentDOB(CurrentIndex), Mark))
```

**Thirdly**, for some reason you are incrementing `CurrentIndex` **three times** in different places thoroughout your code. This will cause your arrays to go out of sync and get "full" very quickly.

Start with `CurrentIndex = 0` then only increment it once ***after*** you've modified all arrays. Preferably after you call `lstOutput.Items.Add(...)`.

**Finally**, I recommend using a [**`DateTimePicker`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_date_time_picker.htm) rather than a `TextBox` for `txtDOB` since it won't allow non-date input.

This also gives you the possibility to specify a minimum and maximum allowed date. To set the maximum date to before today you can put this inside the `Form.Load` event:

```
dtpDOB.MaxDate = Date.Now.AddDays(-1)
```